# How do I add a constraint to a declarative workflow in WF 4.5?

Tags: constraints, workflow-foundation

Are there any examples of how to create a declarative Constraint in a Windows Workflow Foundation 4.5 Workflow? I've viewed the [samples on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd483375(v=vs.110).aspx), and there aren't any examples of a declarative constraint anywhere in the samples.

Answer (score -1):

[Creating a Constraint Library is not that hard:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee358736(v=vs.110).aspx)
Look at the following replicated code:

```
public static class CustomRulesLibrary
{


    public static ValidationSettings Settings = new ValidationSettings()
                                 {
                                     AdditionalConstraints =
                                             {
                                                 {typeof (Activity), new List<Constraint> {MustBeSomething()}},
                                             }
                                 }; 


    public static Constraint MustBeSomething()
    {
        var element = new DelegateInArgument<Activity>();

        return new Constraint<Activity>
        {
            Body = new ActivityAction<Activity, ValidationContext>
            {
                Argument1 = element,
                Handler = new AssertValidation
                {
                    IsWarning = true,
                    Assertion = new InArgument<bool>(env => (element.Get(env).DisplayName.Length > 2)),
                    Message = new InArgument<string>("Some custom message"),
                }
            }
        };            
    }
}
```

Hope above helps.

Comment: That's copied and pasted from the MSDN page. I'm asking for a visual example in a workflow, not in code.